# Apache camel cannot marshal to JSON from InputStreamCache

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel, marshalling

In Apache Camel I expose a REST service, take its input to call a SOAP service and then I'd like to marshal the SOAP response to JSON. My RouteBuilder looks roughly like this:

```
rest("/api")
 .get("/client/{id}")
 .to("direct:getClient");

from("direct:getClient")
 .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Getting client with id ${id}")
 .process(new GetClientProcessor())
 .marshal().jaxb()
 .to("spring-ws:http://localhost:9000/searchClient?soapAction=search")
 .process(new ClientProcessor())
 .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
```

I get the following error while marshalling the result to JSON:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:275)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.mappingException(SerializerProvider.java:1110)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportMappingProblem(SerializerProvider.java:1135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:69)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:292)
    ...
```

I know why this is happening, as I have turned on stream caching by default. However, I don't know how to fix this **without turning off** stream caching.

I have searched through the Camel documentation, mailing lists and fora, but I haven't found useful information sofar.

Comment: See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798907/jsonmappingexception-with-apache-camel, that helped me and it seems to be a duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JsonMappingException with Apache Camel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798907/jsonmappingexception-with-apache-camel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem had nothing to do with described routes, rather the global rest configuration:

```
RestConfiguration restConfiguration = new RestConfiguration();
restConfiguration.setComponent("servlet");
restConfiguration.setBindingMode(RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode.json);
restConfiguration.setHost("localhost");
restConfiguration.setPort(serverPort);

camelContext.setRestConfiguration(restConfiguration);
```

The third line, setting the binding mode, is unnecessary as I state explicitly when I'd like to map to JSON and also which framework I use. After I remove this line everything works like a charm.

At this moment I don't exactly know how or why this has solved my problem, but I'm happy it did ;)